# Problem in checking CheckBoxes, why only the last edit text gets Strikethrough on?

Tags: java, android

This the code for CheckListDetail.java

```
 public class ChecklistDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

ActivityChecklistDetailBinding binding;
ChecklistViewBinding checklistViewBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityChecklistDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

    binding.btnAddItemDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Here int must be used to get the id, if long used, it doesn't work and always return id=0
    String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
    String content = intent.getStringExtra("content");
 

    String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
    String[] contentSplit = content.split("\n");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < contentSplit.length; i++) {

        // This will copy the variable i into j.
        final int j = i;

        boolean state;

        if (statusSplit[i].equals("1"))
            state = true;
        else
            state = false;

        checklistViewBinding = ChecklistViewBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        binding.linearLayout.addView(checklistViewBinding.getRoot());

        checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.setText(contentSplit[i]);
        checklistViewBinding.checkBox.setChecked(state);
        checklistViewBinding.imgDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
        StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
        spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan, 0, checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.getText().length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        if (checklistViewBinding.checkBox.isChecked())
            checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.setText(spannableString);
        else
            checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.setText(contentSplit[i]);
        
        int finalI = i;
        int finalI1 = i;
        checklistViewBinding.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
                StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
                spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan, 0, checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                
                if (b) {
                    checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.setText(spannableString);
                } else {
                    checklistViewBinding.etChecklistItem.setText(contentSplit[finalI]);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

I get a layout like this image.
[image]

If I check the first item which is (a) but (c) gets modified which is get a Strikethrough. No matter if I check (a), (b) or (c), but only (c) gets a Strikethrough. (a) and (b) don't get Strikethrough. Also if I check (a) after that the the third item which is (c) change to (a) or if I check (b) the third item which is (c) change to (b).

Any ideas?

Comment: You could spend time chasing down this bug, or you could learn the correct way to do what you're attempting. The first thing you should focus on is implementing this as a `RecyclerView` instead of manually adding `View`s to your layout. Any time you're calling `addView()` in Android, you're probably on the wrong path.

Comment: I know, I have to use Recyclerview, but here I want to know what causes this bug?

Comment: Because every time you go through the loop, you're reinitializing `checklistViewBinding`. So only the code that executes on the last loop actually gets used when you click on something. Your `OnCheckedChangeListener` is always from the last loop iteration.

Comment: But if I move checklistViewBinding over for loop, the layout only gets one item.

Comment: You would need `checklistViewBinding1`, `checklistViewBinding2`, `checklistViewBinding3`, etc... Again, this is a horrible idea and you should learn `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245914/discussion-between-omer123-and-gavin-wright).